# Debug Symbols not loading

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debug-symbols, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to configure visual studio to enable me to step into the .net framework source code when I am debugging.

I have tried with both Visual Web-Developer-Express-2010 and Visual-Studio-2011-Express-For-Web as well as Visual-Studio-2011-Express-For-Web on Win8CP and I am getting the same problem with each.

I have read numerous tutorials on how to set it up and the settings I have I believe to be correct.

Debugging General Settings -

[image: debug general settings one]

also -

[image: debug general settings two]

Debugging Symbol Settings -

[image: debug symbol settings]

I have tried both of these symbol servers. When I click `Load all Symbols` this is the output I get saying symbol loads have failed -

[Large scale version link](http://i240.photobucket.com/albums/ff34/BrownWarrior/symbolloaddingerror/visual-studio-2011-web-express-beta__no_symbols_found__2012_03_21__09.jpg)
[image: failed symbol loads output]

If I run the code to the breakpoint, right click and select the specific method to step into like so -

[large scale version link](http://i240.photobucket.com/albums/ff34/BrownWarrior/symbolloaddingerror/visual-studio-2011-web-express-beta__no_symbols_found__2012_03_21__08.jpg) 
[image: example of how I try to step into source code]

I get this tab -

[Large scale version link](http://i240.photobucket.com/albums/ff34/BrownWarrior/symbolloaddingerror/visual-studio-2011-web-express-beta__no_symbols_found__2012_03_21__06.jpg)
[image: failed loads error tab]

If I look in my SymbolCache folder, there is only a FailedLoads folder with these contents -

[Large scale version link](http://i240.photobucket.com/albums/ff34/BrownWarrior/symbolloaddingerror/visual-studio-2011-web-express-beta__no_symbols_found__2012_03_21__10.jpg)
[image: FailedLoads folder contents]

My project is in debug mode. I have also tried running VS as administrator. I have full control over the SymbolCache directory. I am on a home network and have full access to my internet connection.

Why is this not working?

Comment: Please vote on fixing this issue here:  http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2710159-fix-broken-net-framework-source-stepping-caused-b

Comment: Not sure if they've included Beta symbols, since MS says it is not their policy to do so, but you may try [downloading one of the Preview packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028#Download_windows).

Comment: Have you tried using JetBrains dotPeek as a symbol server? -- It downloads / decompiles assemblies that you don't have access to and generates the pdbs / source code so that Visual Studio can step through them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Source stepping is only available for RTM or SP releases.

See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/refsourceserver/thread/1b74f60c-e961-425c-a38e-362406dd4cfe.

[Since 4.5 assemblies keep the same version number as 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/09/26/compatibility-of-net-framework-4-5.aspx) ([stupid idea](http://www.devproconnections.com/content1/topic/net-framework-45-versioning-faces-problems-141160/catpath/net-framework)), then there is no way to get compatible symbols + source right now, so this is impossible with VS11 installed.  You must start over with a clean machine and don't install .NET 4.5.

This is really stupid … the whole point of versioning just thrown out the window.

Comment: Funky, does this match your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you [set up the environment](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/4a5fc801-bc83-4f8a-8623-17ec98418685) to load the symbols (note: by default, the symbols are not set to load - have not checked VS 11, btw (will do so later)).

You can also check out this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/) for info on symbols. I will have to check if there is a manual download for symbols for .NET.

You can also set up source server manually to http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols. You cannot browse the reference source.

Comment: Hi Gregory, I can't see any difference in the settings in the link you gave and the settings I have listed above. I believe the settings I have in the debug options are correct. Perhaps there is a setting somewhere else in the options menu or some other issue?

Comment: Check that you have a symbols directory set up on the drive. Then check and make sure that directory is set up in options. The other possibility is an inability to reach the symbols directory at Microsoft, which, offhand, I would look at some type of network sniffer like WireShark to see if it is getting the symbols. If that is happening, it is most likely either a port is not allowed out of your organization or you have proxy set up incorrectly. Added more to answer.

Comment: BTW, as soon as you set up the source server (just did in VS 11 on this box) the symbols will be downloaded. Make sure you have all of the boxes checked as in the first link and you should get symbols for the current project as soon as you close the box.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have tried setting up a new folder to cache the symbols in. When I run the project I immediately see a dialog saying it is downloading mscorlib symbols. But then when I get to the method I wish to step into I still get the same problem. I had a look in the cache folder to see if there was anything there and all there is, is a FailedLoads folder with about 30 files in it. I also opened up fiddler but did not see any request traffic after I clicked to step into the code and got the error.

Comment: It sounds like it is having an issue hitting the site and pulling the symbols. Other than watching the network traffic (not sure how to watch for fails), I am not how to debug the issue. If this is a work network, I would watch what port the download is trying to use and see if it is restricted (if 80 or 443 (standard http) no problem, of course). Fiddler only watches things that are proxied through it (and possibly only http), so you would have to make it your primary proxy to have any chance of seeing anything. WireShark is a sniffer, so it will show more (wireshark.org).

Comment: Thanks for the wireshark tip. It's the first time I have used it. I opened it up, started capturing, went into visual studio and the debugger symbol settings. I clicked 'load symbols' and it tried to load the symbols but I did not see any related traffic in wireshark. Wireshark was working because I saw other traffic, I also opened the VS web browser and saw traffic from that, but not any when trying to load symbols. Also I am on a home network.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem - no symbols loading - and spent a week trying to solve it.  My problem was that I had for the first time started using Master pages in my website project.  And I was incorrectly creating the content pages; the error was that i was not indicating the codebehind file in the page directive of the content page so my codebehind file was in essence unconnected to the build of the project.  A dumb mistake and simple fix after a week of frustration.  Hope this helps some lost programming soul stuck with the same problem.